# WCF Task based asynchronous callback

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, callback, task-parallel-library

I have created WCF service in VS2015:

```cs
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IMyCallback))]
public interface IMyService { }
```

`IMyCallback` looks like:

```cs
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyCallback {

[OperationContract]
Task<string> OnServerEvent(UserAppEventData evData);
```

I've built the server, run it, then added service reference (by right click on solution explorer).
The client object is defined as

```cs
 [CallbackBehaviorAttribute(
     ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant,
     IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true,
     UseSynchronizationContext = true,
     ValidateMustUnderstand = true
)]
public class QMyClient : IMyCallback { }
```

Automatically generated interface implementation made method in sync manner:

```cs
public string OnServerEvent(UserAppEventData evData) { }
```

This code does't work (and isn't asynchronous) and hangs client at `OnServerEvent`.

When I changed code manuallly to

```cs
public async Task<string> OnServerEvent(UserAppEventData evData)
```

**and have done the same** in  auto generated "service `references\...\Reference.cs`, all works fine. But I don't want to change `Referenece.cs` every time I'm updating Service Reference.

Is there any method to force "Update Service Reference" make TBA `OperationContractAttribute` on callback?

At ordinary `WCF` service direction everything works OK, VS generates task based operations.

Comment: You can avoid using "add service reference" in VS. Add the reference of the service assembly where ServiceContract is defined. Create a client proxy class that will extend ClientBase<IMyService> class. Next you can call await OnServerEvent(). Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @VMAtm suggested will work out just fine.

I think, you could also use ChannelFactory for this scenario. It is very flexible and you can then await on the service operations from client side. Additional benefit, you don't need to modify client when there are these kind of changes on service side.

Something like:

```
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(
                    "WSHttpBinding_IService" // endpoint name
                    ); 

IService channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

string result = await channel.OnServerEvent();

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Please note that for this scenario, you will have to import common interface library to client side as dll because then it will need to know about contracts and data contracts.

Answer (score 2):

By default the service reference you've added to solution [**doesn't** have asynchronous operations](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/wcf/983/wcf-task-based-async-pattern-dotnet-45), but you can enable them and decide which option you use for your `async` methods - task-based or old-fashion asynchronous. This option is available in `Advanced` settings for service reference.

[image]

If you're using a `svcutil` tool, it will create the task-based methods [by default](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/endpoint/2010/11/12/simplified-asynchronous-programming-model-in-wcf-with-asyncawait/), however, you can change that behavior by some flags like `/async` or `/syncOnly`.

Comment: Thank You for reply. Unfortunately it's work for straight service interface only. **Not for CallbackContract**. I use to use "generate TB operations" option. I have played with some options of svcutil. No result. It is possible to generate Begin/End async pair for callback methods, but not TBA.